# Call some java code when Http Status/Error Code is received

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Mentioned below is how we redirect to a specific error page when the mentioned error code is received ..

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>400</error-code>
  <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>401</error-code>
  <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

My question is whether there is a way to call a method when any of the above mentioned error-code is received?

Let's suppose there is a bad request and server redirects to error.jsp. Fine. But can't we call some code snippet which would record the received error code before the server redirects to the error page?

I did look up for it over the INTERNET but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own ExceptionHandler web servlet and then in your web.xml change the error-page location attribute from some jsp to this ExceptionHandler. [Here is](http://www.journaldev.com/1973/servlet-exception-and-error-handling-example-tutorial) some example how you can do it. And sure, if you still need it, then you can make redirect to your jsp after ExceptionHandler's job is done.

Comment: well i guess i need to go back to the basics ... i totally forgot this could also be done ... thanks stanislav